# Dynamic Chart.js goes blank on resize

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a [series of dynamically generated graphs](https://pasteboard.co/InFmiQl.gif), displayed using Charts.JS. Initially they all display correctly, however as soon as the user resizes the browser, the charts go blank. They then appear again if you hover over one of the plotted points.

This is for a new website, gathering data from an ASP.net API for various available charts, and then displaying them on a page as cards dynamically.

```
function getReports() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: BaseURL,
        headers: {
            "AuthKey": getCookie("token")
        },
        success: function success(response) {
            console.log(response);
            reports = response;
            $("#reportTemplate").tmpl(response).appendTo("#chrtArea");
            for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
                chartDisplay(reports[i])
            }
        },
        error: function error() {
            alert('Error');
            $(".overlay").hide();
        }
    });
}


function chartDisplay(row) {
    graphs[row.ReportID] = document.getElementById('chrt' + row.ReportID).getContext('2d')
    charts[row.ReportID] = new Chart(graphs[row.ReportID])

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: BaseURL + row.URL,
        headers: {
            "AuthKey": getCookie("token")
        },
        success: function success(response) {
            console.log(response);
            chartData[row.ReportID] = {

                labels: response.Label,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Before SLA',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                    data: response.beforeSLA
                }, {
                    label: 'On SLA',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,140,0, 0.5)',
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                    data: response.onSLA
                }, {
                    label: 'After SLA',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                    data: response.afterSLA
                }]

            };


            charts[row.ReportID] = new Chart(graphs[row.ReportID], {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData[row.ReportID],
                scaleOverride : true,
                scaleSteps : 10,
                scaleStepWidth : 10,
                scaleStartValue : 0,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'SLA (%)'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            ticks : {
                                max : 100,
                                stepValue: 10,                                  
                                min : 0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            })

        },
        error: function error() {
            //alert('Error');
            $(".overlay").hide();
        }
    });

}
```

I feel it could be the way I am dynamically generating them, but i cant think of another way to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

I re-wrote the code, it turned out to be a conflicted variable name somewhere